# Docusign redirect url with dynamic domain name

Tags: integration, docusignapi, docusignconnect

currently my local account have different domain like `"http://tester.company-dev:8080"` , when ever i create an account i will get different domain . how will i set the redirect url in setting page in docusign so that it will redirect me to correct domain url . is it possible to pass a parameter to redirect_url something like below :

```
"http://{domain}.company-dev:8080/ds/callback" and i need to pass the domain value
```

here domain=tester

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the URL for OAuth, mostly used for Auth Code Grant to redirect users back to your app with the code needed to obtain an access token.
You would have to know all the possible URLs and add them to your IK. There's no way to make this dynamic. This is arequirement of OAuth2.0 specification, it's a security issue and you have to have a matching URL. If there's a reason you cannot do that, we can suggest alternate solutions that may involve not using Auth Code Grant and/or some redirect scheme from a fixed URL to one of these dynamic ones.